# Password reset link in email is not found on server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, password-hash, reset-password

Am coding for password reset functionality just using the default routes and default functionality. I am able to receive password reset link in mail, but the links is not working. I am getting 404 error that requested url is not found on server.

As of now I am testing on my localhost

Tried different methods, I know that the token provided in the link, can not visibly match with the token in password_reset table. Just do not have a clue to chase this. As I don't want to customize the whole functionality.

Also I have tried before token expriry only.

The basic routes I am using is

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]); \
//Reset Passwords for candidates 
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request'); 
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email'); 
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset'); 
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

APP URL in .env file is 
APP_URL=http://localhost

I can see the token in password_resets table

What I guess is the token in the mail is different to the token stored in password_resets table, i.e. the hashed values.

What I expect is that the password reset link should work and I should be able to reset the password.

Comment: Do you access your app with `http://localhost` or with another url?

Comment: Well... http://localhost/laravel/public is the root... 

I have tried APP_URL as http://localhost/laravel/public as well...

The link in email was  http://localhost/password/reset/852f55f2b8ff607f8bea56bffb2c90320b00e94a46671729fcf3c11e639a9e56

I did try to cut, change and paste some thing like following.
 http://localhost/laravel/public/password/reset/852f55f2b8ff607f8bea56bffb2c90320b00e94a46671729fcf3c11e639a9e56

I am getting the following error.
Route [password.update] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\auth\passwords\reset.blade.php)

Comment: @YamenAshraf Can you please check this.. Need some help...

Comment: I think this is all about the APP_URL, also development on Windows is pain, consider Homestead and avoid Xampp mamp wamp all these stuff.

Comment: Any other suggestions please..

Answer (score 1):

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

add port if you are on localhost in `APP_URL`

An in my case:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project folder, open the command line, and type `php artisan serve` then `APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8001`